# How to use fscanf in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to write code in MatLab with the purpose to import variables from a text document. It is pretty basic but in the text file I would like to add before each variable what the variable is.

For example:

```
 Amplitude:
 100
```

The struggle I am having is making the fscanf function look for both the string and the integer, which I do not even know is possible. So far what I have is this,

```
fileID=fopen('variables.txt','r');
formatSpec='%d';
sizeA=[1 Inf];
A=fscanf(fileID,formatSpec,sizeA);
dt=1/A(1);
signalSelector=A(2);
BLOCKLENGTH=A(3);
rmsSelector=logical(A(4));
removePeak=logical(A(5));
```

while the text document looks like this,

```
48000 
2 
8192 
0 
0
```

If what I am currently doing is impossible using the fscanf function, is there another function I could use to do this?

Comment: Normally, if you want `fscanf` to read a string (without any spaces) and an integer you would use `"%s%d"`. The fact they are on separate lines does not matter.

Comment: I played around with it a little more and I think i figured out what was confusing me. While playing with the array I saw that it was actually imputing stuff and I just did not realize that the numbers in the array were from the strings. Thanks for you input, it helped me to realize that I was just overlooking that.